# .NETCore Missing some ThreadPool static methods

Tags: .net-core

I'm migrating an app to .NET Core and I'm missing the following ThreadPool static methods:

- GetMinThreads
- GetMaxThreads
- GetAvaialableThreads

Is there a replacement for this?

Comment: They have made it very clear that not everything makes sense on .NET Core, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

You're right that those methods are missing and as far as I know, there is not replacement for them.

But version 1.1 of .Net Core, planned to be released in Fall, should increase compatibility with .Net Framework, so it might contain them.